# Why are TFS event notifications getting filtered?

Tags: tfs

TFS 2017.2 seems to be doing something odd with notifications.. I am watching some process every time, and others get into tbl_eventnotification and then get "filtered" (status = "filtered" in the table).

Can someone point me to an explanation as to why the TFS Notifications engine would "filter" some notifications?

Comment: What is the specific problem this is causing for you? What isn't working? You should have no reason to be running queries directly against the team project collection or configuration databases.

Comment: Except when my client is complaining that their notifications aren't working and notifications are "broken" and you also see that they do an action that should cause a notification, and nothing comes out..

So then you start investigating beyond the UI.. and thats what lead me to see that they are being filtered.. however, I don't know what "filtered" means so I can't explain the behavior to my client :-)..

Comment: Hi @JoshHandel Could you explain more clearly which detail action their were doing and not generated notifications. Did this happens continually or just a randomly issue?

Comment: The client tried several different notification types.. ultimately the one that seemed to fail the most was a workitem state "changed" notification.. with a setting to send the notification to a Team Email address; those would filter pretty regularly.

Comment: @JoshHandel I have set the same notification as you both team email address and personal email account, both worked well, could not reproduce your issue. Have you tried use a personal email account to narrow down the issue if related to your network. Besides what 's the detail "Filter criteria" in your subscription?